# karate api test: how to store all responses of a feature file in an array

Tags: api, karate

Can we store all the responses of all the scenarios in a feature file into a separate json file?
Let me know if that's possible with karate.
Thank you

Comment: The results of all the steps of all the scenarios are available in "target\surefire-reports" as a *.json. You can parse it for the values of your interest.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That json file approach helped.